# ¿Cómo evito errores de truncamiento al tratar de leer e imprimir datos numéricos?

Tags: c++, float

En este ejercicio debo implementar 6 razas de personajes ficticios: Magos, Hobbit, Enanos, Orcos, Trolls y Huargos. Estas razas se encuentran en guerra y se dividen en 2 equipos de 6 miembros cada uno según la siguiente composición: - Equipo 1: Magos(2) , Hobbits(2) y Enanos (2). - Equipo 2: Orcos (2), Trolls(2) y Huargos (2).

Los datos de entrada deben recibirse como el nombre y puntos de ataque de cada personaje en el siguiente orden:

Mago 1
Mago 2
Hobbit 1
Enano 1
Hobbit 2
Enano 2
Orco 1
Huargo 1
Orco 2
Huargo 2
Troll 1
Troll 2
Luego debe realizar las operaciones entre los personajes del mismo equipo para simular el incremento de los puntos de ataque. Los puntos de ataque de los equipos deben ser implementado con las siguientes operaciones:

Los 2 magos sus puntos de ataque conjunto se incrementa en 20%. Ej: (13 +10)*1.2 = 27.60
La combinación de 1 orco y 1 huargo aumenta sus puntos de ataque conjunto en 30%. Ej: (10 +5)*1.3 = 19.50
El equipo con 2 trolls sus puntos de ataque conjunto se incrementa en 15%. Ej: (11 +10)*1.15 = 24.15
La combinación de 1 enano y 1 hobbit incrementan sus puntos de ataque conjunto en 10%. (5+9)*1.1 = 15.40

Los resultados de puntaje de cada equipo deben tener 2 dígitos decimales. Finalmente reportar el resultado si gano el equipo 1, el equipo 2 o si se produjo un empate.

Mi código luce así:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string mago1, mago2, hobbit1, enano1, hobbit2, enano2, orco1, huargo1, orco2, huargo2, troll1, troll2;
    int pts_mago1, pts_mago2, pts_hobbit1, pts_enano1, pts_hobbit2, pts_enano2, pts_orco1, pts_huargo1, pts_orco2, pts_huargo2, pts_troll1, pts_troll2; 
    float equipo1, equipo2;
    
    cin >> mago1;
    cin >> pts_mago1;
    cin >> mago2;
    cin >> pts_mago2;
    cin >> hobbit1;
    cin >> pts_hobbit1;
    cin >> enano1;
    cin >> pts_enano1;
    cin >> hobbit2;
    cin >> pts_hobbit2;
    cin >> enano2;
    cin >> pts_enano2;
    cin >> orco1;
    cin >> pts_orco1;
    cin >> huargo1;
    cin >> pts_huargo1;
    cin >> orco2;
    cin >> pts_orco2;
    cin >> huargo2;
    cin >> pts_huargo2;
    cin >> troll1;
    cin >> pts_troll1;
    cin >> troll2;
    cin >> pts_troll2;
    
    equipo1= (pts_mago1+pts_mago2)*1.20 + (pts_hobbit1+pts_enano1)*1.10 + (pts_hobbit2+pts_enano2)*1.10;
    equipo2= (pts_orco1+pts_huargo1)*1.30 + (pts_orco2+pts_huargo2)*1.30 + (pts_troll1+pts_troll2)*1.15;
    
    cout<<"*** Puntos de ataque de Equipo 1 ***" << endl;
    cout<<"Mago "<<mago1<< " es: "<<pts_mago1<<endl;
    cout<<"Mago "<<mago2<< " es: "<<pts_mago2<<endl;
    cout<<"Hobbit "<<hobbit1<< " es: "<<pts_hobbit1<<endl;
    cout<<"Enano "<<enano1<< " es: "<<pts_enano1<<endl;
    cout<<"Hobbit "<<hobbit2<< " es: "<<pts_hobbit2<<endl;
    cout<<"Enano "<<enano2<< " es: "<<pts_enano2<<endl;
    cout<<"*** Puntos de ataque de Equipo 2 ***" << endl;
    cout<<"Orco "<<orco1<< " es: "<<pts_orco1<<endl;
    cout<<"Huargo "<<huargo1<< " es: "<<pts_huargo1<<endl;
    cout<<"Orco "<<orco2<< " es: "<<pts_orco2<<endl;
    cout<<"Huargo "<<huargo2<< " es: "<<pts_huargo2<<endl;
    cout<<"Troll "<<troll1<< " es: "<<pts_troll1<<endl;
    cout<<"Troll "<<troll2<< " es: "<<pts_troll2<<endl;
    cout<<"*** Empieza el combate ***" << endl;
    cout<<"Los puntos de equipo 1 es "<<setprecision(4)<<equipo1<<endl;
    cout<<"Los puntos de equipo 2 es "<<setprecision(4)<<equipo2<<endl;
    if(equipo1>equipo2){
       cout<<"El equipo 1 gano el combate!!"<<endl;
    }
    else if(equipo2>equipo1){
       cout<<"El equipo 2 gano el combate!!"<<endl;
    }
    else{
       cout<<"EMPATE!!"<<endl;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

El problema con este es que al correrlo me sale un error de truncamiento (-truncated-). Me ayudarían demasiado si me indican cuál es el error por el cual el código tiene problemas de compilación y cómo puedo solucionarlo. Gracias

Comment: No veo ningún error de compilación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te refieres a la cantidad de decimales, [`setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) establece el máximo de decimales a mostrar.

Deberías usarlo en conjunto con [`fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) para que siempre muestre todos los decimales.

Es similar a las configuraciones de una calculadora.

Por ejemplo:

```
cout << setprecision(4) << fixed;

cout << 3.1415926;
// 3.1415
cout << 1.2;
// 1.2000
```